# Move an arbitrary number of args representing paths to files that include a dir or dirs

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I created a script that searches for a pattern using regex inside an email template which is replaced with a variable I extract from a file text and making new files, for example, file.txt file-1.txt file-2.txt, etc.

What I want to do is create a new python script and run it with an arbitrary number of args representing path to a directory to files where I can move the generated files from my working directory. I want to start first with the way I am running the command. Which I might be doing it wrong

```
moveFile.py /path/to/dir/file ./file.txt file-1.txt file-2.txt file-3.txt
moveFile.py ~/*.txt # thinking of just moving them into the root dir

import shutil
import sys
import os

        if os.path.exists(sys.argv[1:2]):
            try:
                shutil.move(file_warn, sys.argv[2:])
            except IOError:
                print("Something Went Wrong On ")
        # removes file ending in ".txt" from working dir
        for files_tobe_removed in os.getcwd():
            if files_tobe_removed.endswith(".txt"):
                os.remove(files_tobe_removed)
```

Forgot to mention I am using windows if that is helpful

Comment: can you be more specific on where (at which step) exactly you want help? Will be easier for me to help quickly.

Comment: I might have to delete my question because I don't even know how to explain in-depth detail.  This is my clearest question if it is futile I will then delete the thread. 
So I need help figuring out how can my script take arbitrary number of paths as arguments and for each argument move them to a root directory or any directory that is not where I have the py script running.  I hope this make sense and thanks